# Managed bean is sometimes null and sometimes not

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf

I have a managed bean LoginBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private String email, password;
    private BasicUser user;

    /** Creates a new instance of LoginBean */
    public LoginBean() {
    }

    public void setUser(BasicUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public BasicUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

   ...
 }
```

And then a PhaseListener who gets the sessions loginBean.

```
public class FacebookSignInListener implements PhaseListener, UserService {
private LoginBean bean;    
....

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) event.getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    bean = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("loginBean");
    bean.setUser(facebookUser);
}
    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    boolean isLoginPage =
            (fc.getViewRoot().getViewId().indexOf("welcome") > -1);
    if (isLoginPage) {
        try {
            FBOauth fbo = new FBOauth(this);
            fbo.doLogin(request);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FacebookSignInListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not exchange code for access_token. Page where not found.", ex);
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean authFacebookLogin(String accessToken, FacesContext fc) throws FacebookException {
        if (accessToken != null) {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
            User fbUser = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);

            UserHelper uh = new UserHelper();
            FacebookUser facebookUser = (FacebookUser) uh.getByFacebookId(fbUser.getId());           
// Does the user already exist and is he already connected with facebook.
            if (facebookUser != null) {             
                return true;
            }
         }
      }
}
```

When I after deploy on the admin console press launch application, logs into my application via facebook there is no problem with the code below. I can logout and log in again and still no problem. If I then change browser and tries to login via facebook here I get a NullPointerException where I do

> bean.setUser(facebookUser)

This also happens if I close the first browser, opens again and tries to login via facebook. Why is this happening?

I am using Glassfish v3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the session scoped bean is `null` then it simply means that it hasn't been created for the session yet. This can happen during the very first request of a fresh session. You've to create it yourself and put it in the session scope yourself. JSF will just reuse it in the remnant of the session.

Your way of grabbing the session scoped bean is a bit clumsy. You're getting the raw Servlet API from under the JSF's hoods. You could also just use [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29) to manage the session attributes.

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
LoginBean loginBean = (LoginBean) sessionMap.get("loginBean");
if (loginBean == null) {
    loginBean = new LoginBean();
    sessionMap.put("loginBean", loginBean);
}
// ...
```

Note that you shouldn't declare the bean as an instance variable of the `PhaseListener`. There is namely a single `PhaseListener` instance throughout the application's lifetime, so all instance variables would be shared among all requests/sessions. In other words: it's not threadsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are trying to use the bean before it was created since your PhaseListener is firing in the first Phase. Have you tried to shift it to a later phase?

Edit:
You access the session with the crate flag set to true:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(true);
```

Thus, your newly created session wont include any session scoped beans. 
The Framework will instantiate the session scoped Bean and put in the session object when an expression referencing the bean is evaluated, which is not the case here.

Comment: The boolean flag doesn't force the session being refreshed. It just instructs the servletcontainer to create new one if it didn't already exist. The cause is indeed due to hooking on a too early phase (when the bean isn't created yet) as in your 1st sentence.

Comment: Right, but it in case there is no active session it will create a new one. In that case the session scoped bean wont be availabel. Or am I missing something here? ;-)

Comment: Your answer is implying that it's caused by setting the create flag to true. This is wrong.

Comment: I made the PhaseListener listen on RENDER_RESPONSE, but the problem remains when I move the code to beforePhase, which I need because (if not) something has been written to ResponseStream and then I cannot redirect. The weird thing is that this does not happen the first time after pressing launchin the admin console. Just as described above.