# IllegalStateException on redirect

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf

I have a PhaseListener which listens on phaseId RENDER_RESPONSE. This faceListener calls this method:

```
   public void doLogin(ServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String code = req.getParameter("code");
        if (StringUtil.isNotBlankString(code)) {
            String authURL = Facebook.getAuthURL(code);
            URL url = new URL(authURL);
            try {
                ....
                if (accessToken != null && expires != null) {
                    boolean isLoginOk = service.authFacebookLogin(accessToken);
                    if (isLoginOk) {
                        fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(fc, "/welcome.xhtml", "logged-in");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Access token and expires not found");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (FacebookException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(FBOauth.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Facebook error", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private String readURL(URL url) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        int r;
        while ((r = is.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write(r);
        }
        return new String(baos.toByteArray());
    }
```

When it redirects I get the following exception which I cant really find any solution to. From what I understand it is thrown because response is already comitted but why is it already comitted?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException at 
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:522)
                at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:572)
                at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:182)
                at wmc.web.facebook.FBOauth.doLogin(FBOauth.java:57)
                at wmc.web.listeners.FacebookSignInListener.afterPhase(FacebookSignInListener.java:56)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
```

By the way I really appreciate all the help I get in here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phaselistener is apparently hooking on `afterPhase` of `RENDER_RESPONSE`. It's too late to change the response then. The response is already been sent to the client. Rather hook on `beforePhase()` of the `RENDER_RESPONSE.

Comment: I've done that :) but now I am back to the problem from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225014/managed-bean-is-sometimes-null-and-sometimes-not which is updated to its current version

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that before the `sendRedirect()` is executed some part of your code has already streamed text to the servlet repsonse, maybe some generic information that is send to all responses?